# ¿Cómo puedo pasar estos parámetros Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Buen día estoy intentando pasar los parámetros `$fecha_inicio`,`$fecha_fin` para luego tomarlos en la siguiente línea de código pero resulta que cuando hago un `dd($fecha_inicio.$fecha_fin)` obtengo esas 2 variables vacías ya que php me las define como nuevas variables y no como los parámetros que recibió en el método `show`

Mi Código

```
public function show($fecha_inicio,$fecha_fin)
    {
        $tipoUsuarioActivo=Auth::user()->tiposUsuarios()->wherePivot("activo", "=", TRUE)->first();
        $grupos=Auth::user()->asistente->gruposMinisterio("array");
        $sobres = DB::table('man_tmp_vision')
        ->whereIn('id_grupo',$grupos)
        ->whereNotExists(function($query)
        {
            $query->select(DB::raw('grupo_id'))
            ->from('reporte_grupos')
            ->whereRaw('reporte_grupos.grupo_id = man_tmp_vision.id_grupo')
            ->whereBetween('reporte_grupos.fecha', [$fecha_inicio,$fecha_fin]);
        })
        ->select('id_grupo','n_grupo','n_lider','n_auxiliar','n_general','n_distrital')
        ->orderBy('n_general','ASC')->paginate(10);
        return \View::make('reportes/sobre/index',compact('sobres'));
    }
```

Comment: Como es eso de que "php me las define como nuevas variables"? Prueba con `dd([$fecha_inicio, $fecha_fin])` y si te devuelve un array vacío, es que las variables llegan vacías desde donde sea que están llegando.

Comment: Supongo que son strings, en la primera línea dentro de tu función: `dd('show()', $fecha_inicio.' - '.$fecha_fin);` para saber si se está llamando y que recibe las fechas.

Comment: al hacer el fuera el dd($fecha_inicio, $fecha_fin) fuera del whereNotExists(function($query) si hay datos al llamar esos parámetros en  ->whereBetween('reporte_grupos.fecha', [$fecha_inicio,$fecha_fin]); las variables están nulas

Comment: Ah, ok! te falta `whereNotExists(function($query) use ($fecha_inicio, $fecha_fin)`

Comment: Gracias así me funciono

Comment: @AuxiliarDeTecnología puedes marcar como aceptada la respuesta que te ha servido o agregar tu propia respuesta a la pregunta para quienes lleguen a este post con el mismo problema

Answer (score 0):

Agrégale `use ($fecha_inicio, $fecha_fin)` a la función en el método `whereNotExists`:

```
$sobres = DB::table('man_tmp_vision')
            ->whereIn('id_grupo',$grupos)
            ->whereNotExists(function($query) use ($fecha_inicio, $fecha_fin) {
                $query->select(DB::raw('grupo_id'))
                    ->from('reporte_grupos')
                    ->whereRaw('reporte_grupos.grupo_id = man_tmp_vision.id_grupo')
                    ->whereBetween('reporte_grupos.fecha', [$fecha_inicio,$fecha_fin]);
            })
            ->select('id_grupo','n_grupo','n_lider','n_auxiliar','n_general','n_distrital')
            ->orderBy('n_general','ASC')->paginate(10);
```